# loading libraries needed by a jsp at runtime

Tags: java, jsp, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

Im forwarding a request from a servlet to dk.jsp . the libraries needed to run the dk.jsp are in "WEB-INF/dk" to avoid jar conflicts .As I dont have control of the dk.jsp (third party JSP), I want to load all jars in "dk" before calling that 
jsp . Im finding it difficult to do it . Please help me in this case .

Comment: the jar(library) which runs JSP are servlet.jar and it mostly is included in servers like tomcat jboss . you dont need to add it explicitly.

Comment: Don't know your use case but use `URLClassLoader ` to load the jars and post some code after that if you get any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't isolate JARs for a JSP like that. JAR files have to be directly under WEB-INF/lib.

What you can do is create a separate web application with just the dk.jsp (and associated JARs) and then forward requests from your web application to the web application providing the dk.jsp. You'll need to enable crossContext support on the web application you are forwarding requests from.